# Error compiling COBOL in AS/400: Program PROGRAM not create in library TEST1 because of source statement

Tags: error-handling, compiler-errors, compilation, ibm-midrange, cobol

I get an error when I'm trying to compile a cobol program as a member in the PUB400.COM IBM i Series free hosting.

I follow an example same as descripted in this video:

https://onx.la/4521a

When compile, I get this error message:

Program USOVAR not create in library TEST1 because of source statement    +

But I don't know how to get more information about the message and how to get the log error or debug a member that is not compiled yet.

This is the code:

```
*************** Beginning of data ************************************* 
0001.00        IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                                         
0002.00        PROGRAM-ID.    USOVAR                                            
0003.00        AUTHOR.        REINALDO ENRIQUE URQUIJO YANIEZ.                  
0004.00        DATE-WRITTEN.  24/03/2022.                                       
0005.00        ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.                                            
0006.00        DATA DIVISION.                                                   
0007.00        WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                         
0008.00        77 WKS-NOMBRE                 PIC A(30).                         
0009.00        01 WKS-REGISTRO-EMPLEADO.                                        
0010.00           02 WKS-NOM-EMP.                                               
0011.00              03 WKS-NOMBRE-TRAB      PIC A(20)                          
0012.00                                        VALUE "PEDRO".                   
0013.00              03 WKS-APELLIDO-PATERNO PIC A(20)                          
0014.00                                        VALUE "PEREZ".                   
0015.00              03 WKS-APELLIDO-MATERNO PIC A(20)                          
0016.00                                        VALUE "ROJAS".                   
FMT CB ......-A+++B+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
0017.00           02 WKS-EDAD                PIC 9(02)                          
0018.00                                        VALUE 48.                        
0019.00           02 WKS-SALARIO             PIC 9(05)V99                       
0020.00                                        VALUE 788.22.                    
0021.00        66 WKS-APELLIDOS-TRAB RENAMES                                    
0022.00              WKS-APELLIDO-PATERNO THRU WKS-APELLIDO-MATERNO.            
0023.00        01 WKS-BANDERA PIC 9(01).                                        
0024.00           88 WKS-TRUE  VALUE 1.                                         
0025.00           88 WKS-FALSE VALUE 0.                                         
0026.00        77 GASTOS                     PIC 9(05)V99.                      
0027.00        77 WS-HORAS                   PIC 9(10).                         
0028.00        01 WKS-DIRECCION              PIC X(30)                          
FMT CB ......-A+++B+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
0029.00                                        VALUE "AV SIEMPRE VIVA 123".     
0030.00        PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                              
0031.00        00001-PRIMER-SECCION SECTION.                                    
0032.00        00001-MIPARRAFO.                                                 
0033.00            DISPLAY "BIENVENIDO AL PROGRAMA".                            
0034.00            DISPLAY "PROGRAMA DE VARIABLES"                              
0035.00            ACCEPT WKS-NOMBRE.                                           
0036.00            DISPLAY "HOLA,"       WKS-NOMBRE.                            
0037.00            DISPLAY "REGISTRO EMPLEADO: " WKS-REGISTRO-EMPLEADO.         
0038.00            DISPLAY "EDAD: "      WKS-EDAD.                              
FMT CB ......-A+++B+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ 
0039.00            DISPLAY "NOMBRE: "    WKS-NOM-TRAB.                          
0040.00            DISPLAY "APELLIDOS: " WKS-APELLIDOS-TRAB.                    
0041.00            DISPLAY "DIRECCION: " WKS-DIRECCION.                         
0042.00            DISPLAY "GASTOS: "    WKS-GASTOS.                            
0043.00            DISPLAY "BANDERA: "   WKS-BANDERA.                           
0044.00            STOP "PAUSA".                                                
0045.00            STOP RUN.                                                    
    ****************** End of data ****************************************
```

Comment: Did you look at the compile listing? That should tell you exactly what the problem was. It is in your spool file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a source member from your code named TEST0017CB. Srctype CBLLE.

Compiled the code using option 14 in PDM. CRTBNDCBL

```
CRTBNDCBL ??PGM(WLKLIB/TEST0017CB)
          ?*SRCFILE(steve/QRPGLESRC)
          ?*SRCMBR(TEST0017CB)
          ??REPLACE(*YES)
```

The compile failed. Ran WRKJOB command. Option 4. spooled files. The compile output listing is the last spooled file in the list. Use option 5 to display the compile listing.

got these compile errors

```
    STMT
 *     2  MSGID: LNC0810  SEVERITY: 10  SEQNBR:  000200
          Message . . . . :   Module name 'TEST0017CB' does not match outermost
            PROGRAM-ID name 'USOVAR'. Accepted.
 *    30  MSGID: LNC1326  SEVERITY: 30  SEQNBR:  003900
          Message . . . . :   'WKS-NOM-TRAB' not defined name. Statement or
            clause ignored.
 *    33  MSGID: LNC1326  SEVERITY: 30  SEQNBR:  004200
          Message . . . . :   'WKS-GASTOS' not defined name. Statement or clause
```

corrected the source code:

```
        IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
        PROGRAM-ID.    TEST0017CB.
        AUTHOR.        REINALDO ENRIQUE URQUIJO YANIEZ.
        DATE-WRITTEN.  24/03/2022.
        ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
        DATA DIVISION.
        WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
        77 WKS-NOMBRE                 PIC A(30).
        01 WKS-REGISTRO-EMPLEADO.
           02 WKS-NOM-EMP.
             03 WKS-NOMBRE-TRAB      PIC A(20)
                                        VALUE "PEDRO".
             03 WKS-APELLIDO-PATERNO PIC A(20)
                                        VALUE "PEREZ".
              03 WKS-APELLIDO-MATERNO PIC A(20)
                                        VALUE "ROJAS".
           02 WKS-EDAD                PIC 9(02)
                                        VALUE 48.
           02 WKS-SALARIO             PIC 9(05)V99
                                        VALUE 788.22.
        66 WKS-APELLIDOS-TRAB RENAMES
              WKS-APELLIDO-PATERNO THRU WKS-APELLIDO-MATERNO.
        01 WKS-BANDERA PIC 9(01).
           88 WKS-TRUE  VALUE 1.
           88 WKS-FALSE VALUE 0.
        77 GASTOS                     PIC 9(05)V99.
        77 WS-HORAS                   PIC 9(10).
        01 WKS-DIRECCION              PIC X(30)
                                        VALUE "AV SIEMPRE VIVA 123".
        PROCEDURE DIVISION.
        00001-PRIMER-SECCION SECTION.
        00001-MIPARRAFO.
            DISPLAY "BIENVENIDO AL PROGRAMA".
            DISPLAY "PROGRAMA DE VARIABLES"
            ACCEPT WKS-NOMBRE.
            DISPLAY "HOLA,"       WKS-NOMBRE.
            DISPLAY "REGISTRO EMPLEADO: " WKS-REGISTRO-EMPLEADO.
            DISPLAY "EDAD: "      WKS-EDAD.
    *** change WKS-NOM-TRAB to WKS-NOMBRE-TRAB
            DISPLAY "NOMBRE: "    WKS-NOMBRE-TRAB.
            DISPLAY "APELLIDOS: " WKS-APELLIDOS-TRAB.
            DISPLAY "DIRECCION: " WKS-DIRECCION.
    *** change WKS-GASTOS to GASTOS
            DISPLAY "GASTOS: "    GASTOS.
            DISPLAY "BANDERA: "   WKS-BANDERA.
            STOP "PAUSA".
            STOP RUN.
```